# Spring AOP pointcut differentiated by arguements

Tags: java, spring-aop

I have two public methods in same class with same return type, only different is the argument it takes. I want to have a pointcut apply on only one of it.

Here is the example of the class:

```
public class HahaService{

    public MyObject sayHaha(User user){
        //do something
    }

    public MyObject sayHaha(Long id, User user){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Now I want to have a pointcut only apply on the 2nd `sayHaha` method which takes two arguments: a `Long` id and a `User` user.

I currently have a `@Pointcut`

```
@Pointcut("execution(public MyObject com.abc.service.HahaService.sayHaha(..))")
private void hahaPointCut() {
}
```

This pointcut is applied on both `sayHaha` method.

Is there a way I can do it only on the 2nd one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just restrict your pointcut expression to methods that have specific parameter types.

Get rid of the `..` and specify the parameter types

```
@Pointcut("execution(public MyObject com.example.HahaService.sayHaha(Long, com.example.User))")
```

Alternatively, if you actually need the value of the arguments, you can use name binding to capture them. For example, your pointcut would be declared as

```
@Pointcut("execution(public MyObject com.example.HahaService.sayHaha(..)) && args(id, user)")
private void hahaPointCut(Long id, User user) {
}
```

and the advice, for example a `@Before`, would be declared as (repeating the names)

```
@Before("hahaPointCut(id, user) ")
public void before(Long id, User user) {
    /* execute advice */
}
```

Now Spring AOP can determine the types of the parameters by the match between the parameters in the pointcut and the names used in `args`. It then matches those in `@Before` and binds to corresponding invocation arguments.

This technique is described in the chapter on [Passing parameters to advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing).